# mysql select query on the basis of a given value not on a primarkey

Tags: mysql

Dear all from the below mentioned table im picking imgurl with this query but not working

```
select imgurl from images where family=shoes;

+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| imgid  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| imgurl | varchar(75) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| family | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: For completeness and to be sure, what is the error...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put "shoes" in quotes for the query to work.  It's a `VARCHAR` type so you need to be sending a string. MySQL puts strings in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

As @babonk said - quoting the `shoes` word will solve your issue:

```
select imgurl from images where family='shoes';
```